# Attempt to de-reference a null object Error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to develop a VF Page that displays record with attachment. But I get the error on the controller of the page which says : Attempt to de-reference a null object  Error.

Here is the code of VF Page:

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false"  controller="Controller004"  sidebar="false" >
<apex:messages />
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Record of avalaible Doctors" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wc}" var="a" columns="4" cellpadding="15px">

 <apex:column headerValue="Name">
 <apex:outputField value="{!a.doctor.Full_Name__c}"  />
 </apex:column>
 <apex:column headerValue="Fee">
<apex:outputField value="{!a.doctor.Fee__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Schedule">
<apex:outputField value="{!a.doctor.schedule__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Photo" >
<apex:image url="{!a.url}" height="300px" width="200px" />
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:form>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And the Controller of the page:

```
    global class Controller004{   
 public List<Doctor__c> obj {get;set;}
 public List<WrapperClass> wc{get;set;}

 public Controller004(){

 obj=[select Full_Name__c, Fee__c, schedule__c from Doctor__c];
 Map<Id,Id> mapDocToAtt = new Map<Id,Id>();
 for(Attachment a : [select id from Attachment where ParentId in:obj])
 { 
    mapDocToAtt.put(a.ParentId, a.Id);
 }

 for(Doctor__c doctor : [select Full_Name__c, Fee__c, schedule__c from Doctor__c])
 {

    wc.add(new WrapperClass(doctor, '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+mapDocToAtt.get(doctor.Id)));

 }
}

 public class WrapperClass{
 public Doctor__c doctor{get;set;}
 public String url{get;set;}
 public WrapperClass(Doctor__c doctor, String url){
 this.doctor=doctor;
 this.url=url;

 }



 }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before adding elements to the list, you have to initialize the list..

```
wc = new List<WrapperClass>();
```

and then you can add the elements to the list in your for loop..

```
for(Doctor__c doctor : [select Full_Name__c, Fee__c, schedule__c from Doctor__c])
{
    wc.add(new WrapperClass(doctor, '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+mapDocToAtt.get(doctor.Id)));
}
```

Comment: @Nishant Make sure you mark the answer as the correct one so future visitors can know it's right, and also so we don't waste our time trying to answer a question that already has an answer.